# Зачем в сеттере используется this? Java

Tags: java, ооп, классы, объекты, setter

Есть код:

```
public class Book {
public void main(String[] args){
    Title title = new Title();
    Author author = new Author();
    Content content = new Content();

    title.setTitle("Bible");
    author.setAuthor("Jesus");
    content.setConetnt("Holy shit");

    title.show();
    author.show();
    content.show();

}

public class Title{
    public String title;

    public void setTitle (String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle (){
        return title;
    }

    public void show (){
        System.out.println(title);
    }
}

public class Author{
    public String author;

    public void setAuthor (String author){
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getAuthor (){
        return author;
    }

    public void show (){
        System.out.println(author);
    }

}

public class Content {
    public String conetnt;

    public void setConetnt (String conetnt){
        this.conetnt = conetnt;
    }

    public String getConetnt() {
        return conetnt;
    }

    public void show (){
        System.out.println(conetnt);
    }

}
}
```

Зачем здесь в методе set используется this?

Comment: Чтобы присвоить значение title из аргумента функции значению title класса. Почитай подробно про то, как работают сеттеры, классы и ООП в целом

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы присвоить значение title из аргумента функции значению title класса. Почитай подробно про то, как работают сеттеры, классы и ООП в целом

Answer (score 1):

this позволяет обращатся к членам класса. В твоем случае для того чтобы скрыть одноименный аргумент метода.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/271963)

Comment: @NTP чего это не является?

Answer (score 0):

В левой части (`this.title`) - обращение к полю класса. В правой части (`title`) - обращение к локальной переменной из аргумента метода-сеттера.

Так как имена поля класса и локальной переменной совпадают, то используется служебное слово `this` для указания на поле класса.
Сама операция присваивает значение локальной переменной, (аргумент метода) полю класса.

PS: служебное слово `this` - ссылка на текущий экземпляр класса и запись `this.title` значит ссылку на глобальную переменную (поле класса) текущего класса с именем `title` (на локальные переменные таким способом ссылаться нельзя, так как они имеют меньшую область видимости, чем экземпляр класса)